# Django 1.4 deprecates ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX but my project was started using Django 1.3 so having issue while using in Django 1.4

Tags: django, compatibility, django-1.3, django-1.4

I started a project in Django 1.3 and have recently installed Django 1.4 on another machine and continued my project on Django 1.4.

Django 1.4 [deprecated the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/releases/1.4/#django-contrib-admin) so I removed it, but now there is some other error that `settings.ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` is not found. So what I can do to make my project work fine with Django 1.4?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Where do you use this setting in your code?

Comment: I didn't use it anywhere myself, if in old version there isn't any thing like that in my project then may be it would be something in other apps, I installed. As I remember I only used smart_select app.

Comment: You should see the exact location with the error. You may be right about this app - see Dirks answer. You can use newest development version.

Comment: @Tadeck thanks, this was what I wanted to konw, because I though that it was somewhere in django-generated code. thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use this setting anywhere in your code or template it can only be raised by a reusable app.

As you mentioned the smart_select app, you might want to have a look at [this changeset](https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects/commit/2d840c6a4fde2c900f8684d6e96061e542e5b006#smart_selects/widgets.py).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the builtin staticfiles app. I fixed the same error by replacing:

```
{% admin_media_prefix %}
```

with:

```
{% static 'admin' %}
```

And you'll need to place `{% load staticfiles %}` at the top of the template.